# Sending a message to a specified discord channel ID with DsharpPlus?

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering who can help me with trying to send a message to a specified channel ID in Dsharpplus C# .net. This is my current assumption but it does not work:

`await discord.SendMessageAsync(discord.GetChannelAsync(ChannelIDHERE), "Hello");`

Here is the error:
[image: Error Image]

Anyone who can help would appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you add error messages as text it's actually possible to read what they say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is not related to DSharpPlus, it's simply an async call not being awaited, this should fix your issue:

```
await discord.SendMessageAsync(await discord.GetChannelAsync(ChannelIDHERE), "Hello");
```